# Ionic view goes blank

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing

i'm having this problem: I have this routing schema for my Ionic app

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})
    .state('tab.plazas', {
    url: '/plazas',
    views: {
        'tab-plazas': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-plazas.html',
            controller: 'PlazasCtrl'
        }
    }
})
    .state('tab.plaza-detalle', {
    url: '/plazas/:plazaId',
    views: {
        'tab-plazas': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/plaza-detalle.html',
            controller: 'PlazaDetalleCtrl'
        }
    }
})

    .state('tab.plaza-diagrama', {
    url: '/plazas/diagramaPlaza/:plazaId',
    views: {
        'tab-plazas': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/diagrama.html',
            controller: 'DiagramaCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

and i want to go to /plazas/diagramaPlaza/:plazaId from inside of plazas/:plazaId, however when i try to do that the app becomes blank, when i test the app at the desktop it works perfectly but the white screen appears when i build the app and test it with my phone.

Any ideas of what could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should first configure an otherwise method for your `route-configuration`  such as

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('your default view');
```

How you transist to other views matters, try using

```
$state.go('tab.plaza-diagrama');
```

this should fix ya problem.

Comment: Woow thanks Damian, using $state.go solved my problem (The one that has screw my mind for two days) Thanks a lot!